# Need helping finding where i went wrong DiscordJS

Tags: javascript

Messing around with a bot dont have any javascript experience so i cant spot where i went wrong,
It saids unexpected token and points to the ) at the end im guessing thats not the issue but something else

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const {
    prefix,
    token
} = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online');
});

client.on('message', message => {

            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
            if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

            else if (command === 'bargun') {
                message.channel.send('bargun number one siege player I get wet when I hear his name');
            } else if (command === 'siege') {
                message.channel.send('Siege is Shit Game');
            } else if (command === 'shaiiko') {
                message.channel.send('Shaiiko is the coolest guy ever i want to be him')
            } else if (command === 'kruzty') {
                message.channel.send('Kruzty is a bitch');

            } else if (command === 'cunt') {
                if (!args.length) {
                    return message.channel.send(`${message.author} is a cunt`);
                    message.channel.send(`${command}\n${args} is a cunt.`);
                };



            }); client.login(token);
```

Comment: Do you have the correct `config.json` file?

Comment: Try putting `client.login(token);` before `client.once()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const {
    prefix,
    token
} = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Online');
});

client.on('message', message => {

            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
            if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

            else if (command === 'bargun') {
                message.channel.send('bargun number one siege player I get wet when I hear his name');
            } else if (command === 'siege') {
                message.channel.send('Siege is Shit Game');
            } else if (command === 'shaiiko') {
                message.channel.send('Shaiiko is the coolest guy ever i want to be him')
            } else if (command === 'kruzty') {
                message.channel.send('Kruzty is a bitch');

            } else if (command === 'cunt') {
                if (!args.length) {
                    return message.channel.send(`${message.author} is a cunt`);
                    message.channel.send(`${command}\n${args} is a cunt.`);
                };
            }


            }); 
client.login(token);
```

you where missing an '}' after the last "else if" statement. This should work

Comment: Great! Please mark my answer as the solution. You should also look into Switch statements, as they are easier to use than many if statements. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp